# SOAP is installed but not showing in phpinfo

Tags: php, web-services, soap, centos, whm

I have a server from `linode.com`, I installed soap from whm-easyapache, when I put this command In `ssh`

> php -i | grep -i soap

It outputs:

```
soap
Soap Client => enabled
Soap Server => enabled
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400
```

When I looked into phpinfo, there is nothing about soap same as php.ini, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

its because the php executable you are using is probably not the one of the web server, it depends on the web server you install (XAMPP, WAMPP, MAMPP, AppServ, etc...), so you have to find the php.ini that apache is currently using

> `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` is for the CLI PHP program, which you found by
>   running php on the terminal.
>
> `/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini` is for the php-cgi system which isn't
>   specifically used in this setup.
>
> `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` is for the PHP plugin used by Apache. This
>   is the one you need to edit for changes to be applied for your Apache
>   setup.

also you can use `locate php.ini` or `find / -name php.ini` to find all php.ini files.

after you do your changes you should restart apache

Comment: I uncommented soap tag every php.ini file i find when i put find / -name php.ini and its still not working (i restarted apache too).

Comment: execute phpinfo() on your web server and search for soap, if its not found there too then you probably done something wrong

Comment: are you sure that the soap files are located as in the path in php.ini

Comment: truth is i dont know cpanel use which php.ini file, but my base php.ini file is /usr/local/lib/php.ini i think, because when i put this command php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File” it outputs the one i write. And in this php.ini file there is nothing about soap.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't see anything, go to apache error log. maybe there is some warnings about it ( after restarting apache server ).

In my apache error log, I saw the following error:

> > PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, by this solution (after a successful installation of soap):

from WHM >> MultiPHP Manager >> check inherited and save , then uncheck and save. now I can see soap in my phpinfo.